# Can Python `sorted` `Key error` report the offending item?

Tags: python, sorting

`all_rates` is a long list of dicts (obtained from screen scraping some web pages), which I sort by some dict key(s):

```
all_sorted_by_BW = sorted(all_rates, key=itemgetter('BW'), reverse=True)
```

This works beautifully, except when a dict in the list happens to have no value for `BW`, in which case I get `KeyError: 'BW'`.

To fix this, I have to get out the list and find the dict with the missing BW (and then remedy, which is easy & fast).

However, it would be nice if the error would report the contents of the offending dict, so I'd know what to look for, rather than having to look for a line (dict) with a value missing. Is that possible at all?

From the [documentation of `sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) and [KeyError](https://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError) I'd say the answer is no, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are not missing anything.

Just test the rates again to find dictionaries without that key:

```
[rate for rate in rates if 'BW' not in rate]
```

The alternative is to wrap each dictionary to report itself when a key is missing, by throwing a more informative exception:

```
class ReportingDict:
    def __init__(self, d):
        self._d = d
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return self._d[key]
        except KeyError:
            raise KeyError(f'{key!r} is missing from {self._d!r}')                

all_sorted_by_BW = sorted(all_rates, key=lambda d: ReportingDict(d)['BW'], reverse=True)
```

Comment: Does this not construct a full dictionary on every iteration?

Comment: @PascalvKooten: it creates a copy, yes.

Comment: @PascalvKooten: created a wrapper class instead, that proxies and re-raises.

Comment: Your first suggestion is actually pretty close to what I was missing :). I can put the `sorted` in a `try` clause and the list comprehension (I think it is that?) in the 'except'.